# Rails 4 - Uikit Single Quotes - Autocomplete syntax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I'm using Rails 4.2.4 and UiKit 2.25.0. I'm trying to use the auto complete component to load my users in a form. The implementation is pretty straight forward (I think).

My main question is about the syntax.

I'm trying to replicate this syntax in my show

```
<div class="uk-autocomplete uk-form" data-uk-autocomplete="{source:'my-autocomplete.json'}">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

But I keep getting this (you may have to scroll horizontally to see):

```
<form class="uk-autocomplete uk-form" id="new_collaboration" data-uk-autocomplete="{source: &#39;users_path&#39;}" action="/lists/3/collaborations" 
  <label for="Enter_collaborator_username">Enter collaborator username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add collaborator" />
 </form>
```

I want single quotes around the source to my json file, but I get

```
&#39; --> data-uk-autocomplete="{source: &#39;users_path&#39;}
```

Could the fact that I'm not seeing single quotes in my source code be the reason it's not working?

I've tried escaping them (\'), but they still show up as &#39.

Here's the link to the Uikit Autocomplete http://getuikit.com/docs/autocomplete.html

Thanks for any help anyone can offer, and please let me know if anyone needs more info from me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, data: { 'uk-autocomplete': "{source:'# {users_path}', method: 'get'}" }) do %>
  <input type="text">
<% end %>
```